# PHP with OAuth for twitter

Tags: php, twitter, command-line, oauth

I am trying to set up an command line tweeting application following this tutorial:

http://www.backupcentral.com/mr-backup-blog-mainmenu-47/13-mr-backup-blog/382-command-line-tweets.html

I have done all steps successfully up until Step 2.2, where the problem is. I do what it tells me, which is `php getreqtok.php $consumer_key $consumer_secret` but I get

> +++2015-07-25T21:58:49+0300:signature_base_string:INFO:normalized_base_string:GET&http%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Doob%26oauth_consumer_key%3D%26oauth_nonce%3D1667013347%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1437850729%26oauth_version%3D1.0
>   +++2015-07-25T21:58:49+0300:getreqtok:INFO:request_url:http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
>   +++2015-07-25T21:58:50+0300:getreqtok:INFO:response_body_parsed:

in the output, when instead I should be getting a URL and a command(?).

About my system: I am running Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.2 (yes, I'm a newbie) and I have installed guest additions and anything else needed to get me up to this point.

The code I have downloaded you can check below (I thought it would be more convenient in Dropbox).

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/m3d92p4hm1f68zc/AABrJOd5IIQWqsIu7ajR1J2oa?dl=0

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Another way is to use hybridauth library

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have a website. I really need this to work on the command line.

Comment: Anyway, I ended up using ttytter which is ready-made and does the same job. It would be nice to figure out this one too, though.